# Native JAI in GeoServer 2.16.0

Tags: geoserver, jai

My group is trying to optimize our GeoServer installation (2.16.0), specially focusing on raster data.

In different posts I've seen some conflicting information regarding the use of Native JAI and Native JAI ImageIO to improve raster performance. From my understanding Native JAI is not supported using JRE 11.

Is it still valid today (Nov 2019) the use of Native JAI to gain this performance?

Also apart from TileCaching are there other optimizations that we can use to serve our tiles faster?

GeoServer is running inside a docker container with Debian 9

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: sorry forgot to add that, I've edited the question to include the info